# Python - login to website using requests

Tags: python, authentication, web

I have to admit I am complitely clueless about this: I need to login to this site https://segreteriaonline.unisi.it/Home.do and then perform some actions. Problem is I cannot find the form to use in the source of the webpage, and I basically have never tried to login to a website via python.
This is the simple code I wrote.

```
import requests

url_from    = 'https://segreteriaonline.unisi.it/Home.do'
url_in      = 'https://segreteriaonline.unisi.it/auth/Logon.do'

data = {'form':'1', 'username':'myUser', 'password':'myPass'}

s = requests.session()
s.get(url_from)
r = s.post(url_in, data)

print r
```

Obviously, what i get is:

```
<Response [401]>
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every site has its own way of loging in. You have to go to the site and analyze how it does. What requests go to what urls. There can be lots of security thingies like CSRF protection. There is no one general way to do that. You have to do your own research.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the requests authentication header.

Please check [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/authentication/):

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
<Response [200]>
```

Answer (score 0):

That site appears to not have a login *form*, but instead uses HTTP Basic auth (causing the browser to request the username and password). requests supports that via the `auth` argument to `get` - so you should be able to do something like this:

```
 s.get(url_in, auth=('myUser', 'myPass'))
```